# Unitary matrices are invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, unitary-matrices

By definition, an unitary matrix $U$ is defined as $U U^H = I$.

How can we prove that an unitary matrix $U$ is invertible? It can happen that $U^H U \neq I$.

Comment: It's enough to see that $detU\neq 0$

Comment: For square matrices, if $A.B = I$ then $B.A = I$.  So perhaps you must add "square matrix" to your definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unitary matrix is by definition a square matrix $U$ over $\mathbb C$ such that
$$U\overline{U}^t = \overline{U}^tU = I. $$

---

I'm assuming $U^H$ means the transpose of the conjugate. Using definition of unitarity and some linear algebra magic, we get $$\det (UU^H) = \det (U) \det (U^H) = \det (U)\det (\overline{U}) = \det (U)\overline{\det(U)} = 1, $$
i.e $|\det (U)|^2 = 1$, which implies $\det (U) = e^{i\varphi}$, hence $U$ is invertible.

Also, for square matrices, $AB = I$ implies
$$BAB = B \Rightarrow BA = I. $$